# A general term for complex exponentiation, i.e. $(a+ib)^{c+id}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So I've tried to make out a general term for complex exponentiation, that is
$$(a+ib)^{(c+id)}$$I could not find any solution to this calculation online, so if anyone could verify my solution or point out any mistake, it would be very helpful.

> Steps are as follows:

Let
$$y = (a+ib)^{c+id}$$

Now, using

$$a^{b} = e^{b\ln{a}}$$

$y = e^{(c+id)(\log{(a+ib)})}$      ......a

Also, using
$$\log{(x+iy)} = \frac{1}{2}\log{(x^{2}+y^{2})}+ i\tan^{-1}({\frac{y}{x}})$$

$\implies(c+id)(\log{(a+ib)}) = (\frac{c}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})}-d\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})})+i(c\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})}+\frac{d}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})})$

$\implies y = e^{(\frac{c}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})}-d\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})})+i(c\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})}+\frac{d}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})})}$

Using
$$e^{ix} = \cos{(x)}+i\sin{(x)}$$

$\implies y = e^{(\frac{c}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})}-d\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})})}(\cos{(c\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})}+\frac{d}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})}})+i\sin{(c\tan^{-1}{(\frac{b}{a})}+\frac{d}{2}\log{(a^{2}+b^{2})}))}$

Any confirmation or pointed out mistake would be very helpful. Thanks in advance...

Comment: $\arctan(y/x)$ should be [$\operatorname{atan2}(y,\,x)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be strict and avoid confusion because of the arctangent, write it is as
$$\left(a^2+b^2\right)^{c/2} e^{-d \theta}\Bigg[\cos \left(\frac{d}{2}  \log \left(a^2+b^2\right)+c \theta\right)+i \sin \left(\frac{d}{2}  \log \left(a^2+b^2\right)+c \theta\right) \Bigg]$$ where $\theta=\arg (a+i b)$.

Comment: But is the rest of the calculation correct? Please do tell...